# What happens when you overpower the grid?

Tags: into-the-breach

When you have a full grid and you buy some "+1" power with a star, it's called "Overpower grid" and it says :

"Your Power Grid is full. Additional Power will permanently upgrade your Grid Defense" which I understand.

But it also says: "The bonus will decrease the higher your Grid Defense gets, to a maximum of +25", what does this mean? What will decrease exactly? How can it reach a "maximum" when it's "decreasing"? Is it a typo?

Comment: You'll get less additional bonus for each +1, so the increase from +24 to +25 will be a lot less than +0 to +1, and nothing will happen if you upgrade past +25 (if you even can).

Comment: There is no 'from +0 to +1' in this game, u start at 18

Comment: No, the grid overpower bonus

Comment: U don't overpower the grid at all when it's full. U only get a grid defense bonus instead

Comment: Yeah, but isn't the defense bonus _called_ overpower bonus?

Comment: Ok, so what does the 'less' mean in : "the increase from +24 to +25 will be a lot less than +0 to +1" ? What will be less than what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74974/discussion-between-somebody-and-tristan).

Comment: `How can it reach a "maximum" when it's "decreasing"?` Simply put, [diminishing returns (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Grid Defense starts at 15%, and can be increased by gaining additional power after the Power Grid is full. This is called Overpower Bonus, and can get as high as an additional 25%.

Up to a 10% Overpower Bonus, each point of overpower will increase the Grid Defense by 2%. After that, each point of overpower will increase the Grid Defense by 1% instead. This is how the bonus decreases the higher your Grid Defense gets.

Comment: There's also apparently a hard cap but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: Ok, nicely explained. I've also discovered there is an independant additional "Pilot bonus" for grid defense, not affected by the 25% cap.